# gnuplot: how to draw boxes with specific width, height and color

Tags: colors, gnuplot

I would like to draw 60 boxes next to each other (not overlapping). Width should be according to specific column, height should be according to specific column, as well as color ant title. As titles I want just number all boxes from 1 to 60.

Please, how can I do this?

(I know, that third column makes automatically specific width, but boxes are overlapping and I wouldnt be pleased by recalculating x positions. I havo also experienced setting color with rgb variable. However, how to do all these things at once, I do not know. Thank you very much for your suggestions)

Comment: Are you sure you want to use gnuplot for this? gnuplot is good in plotting data. For painting data, maybe an other tool is more suited!?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you do this with ImageMagick. In gnuplot you can however do it with:

```
set object 1 rect from x1,y1 to x2,y2
set label 1 at x3,y3 "yourlabel" front center
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have a data file with columns for label, width, height and color.
The plotting style `with boxes` offers 2 and 3 column syntax:

> ```
>      2 columns:  x  y
>      3 columns:  x  y  x_width
> ```

The "trick" to avoid overlapping of the boxes is simply adding up the x-coordinates in `x0`.

**Data:** `SO8742082.dat` (with some random width, height and color)

```
#    width       height      color     
 1   1.25559     90.5915     0xbc2d76
 2   1.87402     40.3925     0xa10862
 3   1.12711     60.5378     0x0247e8
 4   2.95355     105.314     0x6b8fee
 5   1.75121     103.800     0xd0e30b
 6   1.61134     15.6505     0x42e77e
 7   1.13001     100.190     0x580410
 8   1.15918     27.1352     0x963b2e
 9   2.68129     96.0740     0xf951f4
 10  1.57321     72.9696     0x4afd27
 11  1.78742     41.2944     0xea1933
 12  1.39995     61.9502     0xcc8750
 13  2.75575     96.4659     0xf328e8
 14  2.30559     64.6213     0x549178
 15  2.57415     62.2784     0xe5af89
 16  2.54712     20.2026     0x4eeeb4
 17  2.18039     105.251     0x9dbdc9
 18  1.66738     51.9178     0xe3aa7e
 19  1.11258     84.3438     0xafbb7e
 20  1.26511     75.0783     0xb8f302
```

**Script:** (works at least for gnuplot>=4.4.0, March 2010)

```
### plot boxes with variable width, height, color and label
reset

FILE = "SO8742082.dat"

set xrange[*:*]
set yrange[0:*]
set xtics out
set style fill solid 0.5 noborder
set key noautotitle

plot x0=0 FILE u (x0=x0+$2/2):(x0=x0+$2/2,$3):2:4 w boxes lc rgb var, \
     x0=0   '' u (x0+$2/2):(x0=x0+$2,$3):1 w labels offset 0,1 center
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Alternatively, you could  use the plotting style `with boxxyerror`. There are two options for 4 columns and 6 columns: (check `help boxxyerror`).

> ```
>      4 columns:  x  y  xdelta  ydelta
>      6 columns:  x  y  xlow  xhigh  ylow  yhigh
> ```

As I understand, with variable color (an additional column) you have to use the 6 column syntax, otherwise gnuplot might get confused (works for gnuplot>=4.6.0, March 2012).

```
plot x0=0 FILE u 2:3:(x0):(x0=x0+$2):(0):3:4 w boxxy lc rgb var, \
     x0=0   '' u (x0+$2/2):(x0=x0+$2,$3):1 w labels offset 0,1 center
```